# Ajax Call reload Message

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drupal

I have a AJAX call that returns a boolean response. On `true` I update values in the DB and reload the page where it retrieves the updated listing.

I am trying to show a success message once it has reloaded, how can i do that ?
No flags can be set in db, trying not to mess with the schema.
My Ajax Call :

```
success: function (data) {
  if (data.response === true) {
    location.reload();
    // $('.msg-div').addClass('alert alert-success');
    // $('#msg').text("Successfully Updated Records" );
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: Reloading the page after making an AJAX request make the point of AJAX almost entirely redundant. It would make a lot more sense to return the updated data in the response and dynamically update the DOM without reloading.Then you can display the toast/modal notification in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Using this before my Json response solved the issue for Drupal 8.

```
\Drupal::messenger()->addStatus('Updated Records Successfully');
```